# How can I view posts made with "Facebook Comment Sections" on other websites?

Tags: facebook

I'm seeing blogs as well as a few start-up projects using Facebook Walls as their comments sections. These are integrated with your Facebook account and generates a Facebook Notification when you receive responses to your comments. Clicking the notification takes you to the original website.

Since each of these websites has a separate "Wall" for different content, it is difficult to find your posts if you don't remember where you made the original post.

Is there a way to find posts that you've made to external Facebook Walls on third-party websites?