# Find all Facebook comments on external websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration

Is there any way to find all comments on external websites connected with a Facebook account? Let's say I want to find all my Facebook activity on external pages based on profile URL; is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22074/how-can-i-view-posts-made-with-facebook-comment-sections-on-other-websites http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51443/how-to-find-facebook-comments-i-made-on-website-such-as-9gag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Facebook does not allow the end user who uses Facebook connect to see all of your information across the web that uses the Facebook login. [Here's](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/facebook-across-the-web/41735647130) the Facebook page to see how Facebook connect works. Facebook does allow you to see in your account settings which apps/pages you have authorized to connect to your Facebook account, as well as revoke that access.

It may help to read the [Facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) site for developers to see how it works on the site's end.